# Reprojecting raster data from a rotated pole grid

Tags: coordinate-system

I have some raster data (ASCII grid files) that use a custom rotated-pole projection, that I'd like to reproject into something more useful, such as lon/lat WGS84. A description of the grid projection is here, but I can't see how I can use this to create a projection string for use in GIS.

http://ukclimateprojections-ui.defra.gov.uk/ui/docs/grids/prob_land_25km_rotated/index.php

This SE question seems to discuss using rotated pole data, but I can't work out how to apply it to my problem: [Lon/lat transformation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/lon-lat-transformation)

I found a thread here asking exactly same question (about the same dataset), but with no replies: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-March/028174.html

The header of the ASCII grid data looks like this:

```
ncols 39
nrows 52
xllcorner -0.50
yllcorner -0.50
cellsize 1.00
```

Comment: I think this link is useful for you:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/manually-transforming-rotated-lat-lon-to-regular-lat-lon
or if you want use cordex data you can visit this online converter
http://agrimetsoft.com/Cordex%20Coordinate%20Rotation.aspx
Cheers

Comment: Not enough reptuation to comment but maybe check out my answer on another question:
[Manually transforming rotated lat/lon to regular lat/lon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407460/187906)