# Weather data in rotating grid without time dimension or vertical dimension or CRS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, affine-transformation

I am a beginner using QGIS 2.18.15. I am having some trouble to find the right coordinate reference system for   **wind speed data of Europe** from the German Weather forecast service (DWD). (ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_europe/monthly/wind/MIKLIP_DECREG/v002/)

The data is projected in a **regular rotating grid with a virtual North Pole at 39.25 N, 162.00 W** (rotated coordinates). When I add the raster layer to QGIS it tells me that there is **no “pre stetted” CRS** so it automatically uses the CRS EPSG: 4326, WGS 84. As a result the layer of Europe is now half on Africa half on the Atlantic Ocean. So I looked for a possible CRS online but could not find any.

[image]

As the grid is rotating someone told me that the question “[Manually transforming rotated lat/lon to regular lat/lon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/manually-transforming-rotated-lat-lon-to-regular-lat-lon)” might solve my problem. But it does not. In this question we got two data sets. I just have one data set in a rotating grid and I don’t have the according regular coordinate system. Further on I would still need to know the CRS of the out-put coordinates which I could not find online.

Another user told me to have a look at the question "[Transforming data from a rotated pole lat-lon grid into regular lat-lon coordinates in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246258/transforming-data-from-a-rotated-pole-lat-lon-grid-into-regular-lat-lon-coordina)". As I am a total beginner of Python too, I am lost with the presented code. Copying and modifying with my values did not work out. I even still don’t know which CRS I would be supposed to use.

As I am trying everything I also tried affine transformation but as I could not chose my data set as a layer it first did not work out ether. I guessed that’s because my data is a raster-layer and not a vector-layer. So I transformed my raster into a vector layer. That workef out but I recieved this warning.

[image]

The data set seems to have no time dimension or vertical dimension. Now I stack with the spreadsheet. I don’t know what I have to fill in.

[image]

Is this even a right  approach to solve the problem?

Comment: You are not the first one facing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549880/how-to-convert-a-rotated-netcdf-back-to-normal-lat-long, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57756/reprojecting-raster-data-from-a-rotated-pole-grid, https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/43959/netcdf-rotated-coordinate-system-rlat-rlon.html,

Comment: @Marco Thanks for your comment. The answer of the first link you recommended me guides me to [link] (https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/boards/2/topics/102) And here they have data according to  xfirst and yfirst and 
xinc and yinc. Where do i got those datas from?

Comment: The second link guided me to the question I allready mentiont in my question.      the third link https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/43959/netcdf-rotated-coordinate-system-rlat-rlon.html is containing a code but it asspect that we have the south pole data. I only have the north pole data. How can I change the code for that I can use it with the noth pole?