# Re-interpolate a curvilinear NetCDF file into a evenly spaced grid

Tags: raster, netcdf

I have a NetCDF that can be downloaded at https://thredds.socib.es/thredds/catalog/operational_models/oceanographical/hydrodynamics/wmop_surface/catalog.html (e.g. downloading "latest.nc"). The latitude is not evenly spaced (curvilinear), as pointed out in the post [Finding correct projection for raster dataset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/464597/214559).
How can I transform/re-interpolate this dataset into an evenly-spaced dataset that can be correctly plotted in QGIS? Is there an R solution to it or a more straightforward one using e.g. cdo or any other software?