# Warnings on converting NetCDF using gdalwarp

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, netcdf

I have a curvilinear NetCDF file, which currently has a single time step (for a mean across time). The variable I am looking at is DIC at a single depth.
I am trying to convert this NetCDF file to TIFF, and used gdalwarp, which I found here [Handle Curvilinear/rotated grid NetCDF file in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/390148/handle-curvilinear-rotated-grid-netcdf-file-in-r)

I get an output but also several warnings, which may be related to my file being curvilinear. I am new to GIS, so I don’t really understand if these warnings are something to be worried about.

```
Warning 1: dimension #3 (i) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #2 (j) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: No 1D variable is indexed by dimension k
Warning 1: dimension #1 (i) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (j) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #1 (i) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (j) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Creating output file that is 392P x 334L.
Processing NETCDF:mean.nc:DIC [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. 1e+35) for image NETCDF:mean.nc:DIC.
Copying nodata values from source NETCDF:mean.nc:DIC to destination DIC_mean_warp.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Below is the dump from gdal info

```
Warning 1: dimension #3 (i) is not a Longitude/X dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #2 (j) is not a Latitude/Y dimension.
Warning 1: No 1D variable is indexed by dimension k
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: mean.nc
Size is 315, 253
Metadata:
  DIC#cell_methods=time: mean
  DIC#coordinates=latitude longitude
  DIC#long_name=Dissolved Inorganic Carbon
  DIC#missing_value=1e+35
  DIC#puv__parameter=http://vocab.nerc.ac.uk/collection/P01/current/CINCMOD1/
  DIC#units=mg C m-3
  DIC#_ChunkSizes={1,11,598,128}
  DIC#_FillValue=1e+35
  NC_GLOBAL#bald__isPrefixedBy=prefix_list
  NC_GLOBAL#CDI=Climate Data Interface version 2.0.4 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
  NC_GLOBAL#CDO=Climate Data Operators version 2.0.4 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.0
  NC_GLOBAL#date_created=Thu Jun 22 15:14:52 2023
  NC_GLOBAL#description=eReefs GBR 1k grid with rivers. Uses JCU bathy (www.deepreef.org). Created by JA 08.05.2012.  hydrodynamic 2.0 BGC 3.2 cathment constant concentrations.
  NC_GLOBAL#ems_version=v1.4.0 rev(7358)
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=-22.15316
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=-25.168796
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=153.761098
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=150.22234
  NC_GLOBAL#history=Wed Aug 23 12:18:23 2023: cdo timmean -cat *.nc mean.nc
  NC_GLOBAL#Parameter_File_Revision=$Revision: 1945 $
  NC_GLOBAL#paramfile=./tran/gbr1_bgc_nrt.tran
  NC_GLOBAL#paramhead=eReefs 1 km grid. Mile Furnas Catchment constant concentrations. More details of naming protocol at: eReefs.info.
  NC_GLOBAL#prefix_list_puv__=https://w3id.org/env/puv#
  NC_GLOBAL#prefix_list_qudt__=http://qudt.org/vocab/unit/
  NC_GLOBAL#Run_code=GBR1_H2p0_B3p2_Cfur_Dnrt|G0.00|H0.00|S0.0|B2.0
  NC_GLOBAL#Run_ID=2.0
  NC_GLOBAL#title=GBR1_H2p0_B3p2_Cfur_Dnrt
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={time,k}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_DEF={1,6}
  NETCDF_DIM_time_VALUES=11077.5
  time#axis=T
  time#bounds=time_bnds
  time#calendar=gregorian
  time#long_name=Time
  time#standard_name=time
  time#units=days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00 +10
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"mean.nc":time_bnds
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x2] time_bnds (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"mean.nc":longitude
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[253x315] longitude (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=NETCDF:"mean.nc":latitude
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[253x315] latitude (64-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=NETCDF:"mean.nc":DIC
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[1x1x253x315] DIC (32-bit floating-point)
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:"mean.nc":longitude
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:"mean.nc":latitude
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  253.0)
Upper Right (  315.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  315.0,  253.0)
Center      (  157.5,  126.5)
Band 1 Block=315x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=1.00000004091847876e+35
  Unit Type: mg C m-3
  Metadata:
    cell_methods=time: mean
    coordinates=latitude longitude
    long_name=Dissolved Inorganic Carbon
    missing_value=1e+35
    NETCDF_DIM_k=1
    NETCDF_DIM_time=11077.5
    NETCDF_VARNAME=DIC
    puv__parameter=http://vocab.nerc.ac.uk/collection/P01/current/CINCMOD1/
    units=mg C m-3
    _ChunkSizes={1,11,598,128}
    _FillValue=1e+35
```