# What is rotated coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have downloaded a csv file with grid locations with lon/lat for European Extreme Windstorms footprints (attached). However the coordinate system of this dataset is not given.

As per the data description on the website (http://www.europeanwindstorms.org/database/dataDesc/):

The footprints were created using a model with a rotated pole at longitude = 177.5 degrees, latitude = 37.5 degrees (meaning that the z-axis of the new coordinate system lies at longitude = 177.5, latitude = 37.5 degrees. The footprints are on a regular grid in the rotated coordinate system, with horizontal grid spacing 0.22 degrees.

How to build custom coordinate system in ArcGIS using the information above?

I believe my data should fit the square in the image below:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What does the spatial data in a row of your CSV file look like?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/manually-transforming-rotated-lat-lon-to-regular-lat-lon?rq=1 and the questions linked there should help you further.