# Trying to define a "rotated regular grid" coordinate system in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have some raster data whose metadata defines its coordinate system as:

`rotated regular grid, virtual North Pole at 39.25 N, 162.00 W (rotated coordinates)`

Its spatial resolution is `0.044 degree`.

I am trying to get this data into regular longitude, latitude coordinates and to do so I have defined a custom projection with these parameters:

`+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=39.25 +lon_0=-162 +no_defs`.

It doesn't really seem to help though, this is the raster layer and OSM basemap layer, both visualized in WGS84: [image: this]

and this is the same layers, both visualized with this defined coordinate system: [image: this]

I feel like I must be missing something obvious here.  Is this not how you would define a coordinate system for a rotated regular grid?

The source data, as well as the metadata PDF is [here](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/../../pub/CDC/grids_europe/monthly/wind/MIKLIP_DECREG/v001/)

Comment: I don't have time to tease out the actual solution but check out this issue and its discussion: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4285

Comment: You might take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246258/transforming-data-from-a-rotated-pole-lat-lon-grid-into-regular-lat-lon-coordina?rq=1 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/manually-transforming-rotated-lat-lon-to-regular-lat-lon