# QGIS- Can't find fitting CRS (rotated regular grid)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, rotate

I am using QGIS 2.18.15. I got raster layer data’s for wind speeds in Europe.
 (ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_europe/monthly/wind/MIKLIP_DECREG/v002/)
The data description describes the projection as an:

> "rotated regular grid, virtual North Pole at 39.25 N, 162.00 W (rotated coordinates)"

I can add the raster to QGIS but I do not find the fitting CRS. I looked for a possible Coordinate Reference System online but could not find one. Do you have an idea which CRS might suit in this case?

Comment: You might look into https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246258/transforming-data-from-a-rotated-pole-lat-lon-grid-into-regular-lat-lon-coordina?rq=1