# Manually transforming rotated lat/lon to regular lat/lon given north pole coordinate

Tags: coordinate-system, rotate

I am interested in transforming regular coordinates to rotated coordinates similar as done in this post:
[Manually transforming rotated lat/lon to regular lat/lon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/manually-transforming-rotated-lat-lon-to-regular-lat-lon)

These functions base the rotation on the coordinates of the south pole. However, I have a dataset where I am provided north pole coordinates instead (CORDEX data). I am stuck on what I should change in the code. Anyone would know what to do?

South pole rotation code:

```
from math import *

def rotated_grid_transform(grid_in, option, SP_coor):
    lon = grid_in[0]
    lat = grid_in[1];

    lon = (lon*pi)/180 # Convert degrees to radians
    lat = (lat*pi)/180

    SP_lon = SP_coor[0]
    SP_lat = SP_coor[1]

    theta = 90+SP_lat # Rotation around y-axis
    phi = SP_lon # Rotation around z-axis

    theta = (theta*pi)/180
    phi = (phi*pi)/180 # Convert degrees to radians

    x = cos(lon)*cos(lat) # Convert from spherical to cartesian coordinates
    y = sin(lon)*cos(lat)
    z = sin(lat)

    if option == 1: # Regular -> Rotated

        x_new = cos(theta)*cos(phi)*x + cos(theta)*sin(phi)*y + sin(theta)*z;
        y_new = -sin(phi)*x + cos(phi)*y;
        z_new = -sin(theta)*cos(phi)*x - sin(theta)*sin(phi)*y + cos(theta)*z;

    else:  # Rotated -> Regular

        phi = -phi
        theta = -theta

        x_new = cos(theta)*cos(phi)*x + sin(phi)*y + sin(theta)*cos(phi)*z
        y_new = -cos(theta)*sin(phi)*x + cos(phi)*y - sin(theta)*sin(phi)*z
        z_new = -sin(theta)*x + cos(theta)*z



    lon_new = atan2(y_new,x_new) # Convert cartesian back to spherical coordinates
    lat_new = asin(z_new)

    lon_new = (lon_new*180)/pi # Convert radians back to degrees
    lat_new = (lat_new*180)/pi

    print lon_new,lat_new
```

Comment: Would it be possible to deduce the south pole coordinates from the north pole seeing as they are always on opposite sides of the globe?